# How do I setup this has_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-5

So I have a `PortStock` model, that has `action: buy` and `action: sell` enum attributes. Each `PortStock` can be either `position: open` or `position: closed` (also enum values).

However, what closes one `PortStock` is another `PortStock` (i.e. a `PortStock.sell` closes a `PortStock.buy`).

So I created a join model called `ClosedPositions`, and basically what I want to do is record the meta-data around the closing of one `PortStock` by the other.

This is the schema & model for my `ClosedPosition.rb` model:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: closed_positions
#
#  id             :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  closer_id      :integer
#  closed_id      :integer
#  num_units      :integer
#  closed_price   :float
#  dollar_change  :float
#  percent_change :float
#  ticker         :string
#  created_at     :datetime         not null
#  updated_at     :datetime         not null
#

class ClosedPosition < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :closer, class_name: "PortStock", foreign_key: "closer_id"
  belongs_to :closed, class_name: "PortStock", foreign_key: "closed_id" 
end
```

On my `PortStock` model, I have a simple `has_many :closed_positions`.

However, when I try to add a `closed_position` to an existing `port_stock` object, I get an `unknown attribute port_stock_id` error.

```
[27] pry(main)> closer = PortStock.find(8)
  PortStock Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "port_stocks".* FROM "port_stocks" WHERE "port_stocks"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 8], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<PortStock:0x00007fc951a47c30
 id: 8,
 portfolio_id: 1,
 stock_id: 84,
 volume: 250,
 purchase_price: 4.1,
 current_price: 4.0,
 percent_change: -2.43902439024389,
 created_at: Tue, 12 Jun 2018 00:46:09 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Tue, 12 Jun 2018 00:46:09 UTC +00:00,
 current_value: 1000.0,
 dollar_change: -24.9999999999999,
 total_spend: 1025.0,
 bought_on: Sat, 09 Jun 2018 00:00:00 UTC +00:00,
 action: "sell",
 position: "open",
 ticker: "KEY">

[28] pry(main)> closed = PortStock.find(5)
  PortStock Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "port_stocks".* FROM "port_stocks" WHERE "port_stocks"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<PortStock:0x00007fc951a55858
 id: 5,
 portfolio_id: 1,
 stock_id: 84,
 volume: 250,
 purchase_price: 4.1,
 current_price: 4.0,
 percent_change: -2.43902439024389,
 created_at: Mon, 11 Jun 2018 03:11:10 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Mon, 11 Jun 2018 23:28:30 UTC +00:00,
 current_value: 1000.0,
 dollar_change: -24.9999999999999,
 total_spend: 1025.0,
 bought_on: Sat, 09 Jun 2018 00:00:00 UTC +00:00,
 action: "buy",
 position: "open",
 ticker: "KEY">

[34] pry(main)> closer.closed_positions.create(closed: closed, num_units: closer.volume, closed_price: closed.stock.price, ticker: closed.ticker)
  Stock Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "stocks".* FROM "stocks" WHERE "stocks"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 84], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'port_stock_id' for ClosedPosition.
from /.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activemodel-5.2.0/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:53:in `_assign_attribute'
[35] pry(main)> closer.closed_positions.create(closed_id: closed.id, num_units: closer.volume, closed_price: closed.stock.price, ticker: closed.ticker)
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'port_stock_id' for ClosedPosition.
from /.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activemodel-5.2.0/lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:53:in `_assign_attribute'
```

How do I fix this?

Am I approaching this right? I may be messing up the association syntax & logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ActiveRecord was complaining about is that there was no `port_stock_id` column on my `ClosedPosition` model.

So, I simply renamed the column `closed_id` to `port_stock_id`, and then I changed my association in my `ClosedPosition` model from:

```
class ClosedPosition < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :closed, class_name: "PortStock", foreign_key: "closed_id" 
end
```

To:

```
class ClosedPosition < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :closed, class_name: "PortStock", foreign_key: "port_stock_id" 
end
```

Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to create closed_positions record, ActiveRecord assumes a foreign key `port_stock_id` to be present which in this case is not present. So try the solution below add the has may associations. I added both (I don't know its relevance in terms of current context). This way you will be able to create associated records.

`class PortStock < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :closed_stock_positions, foreign_key: 'closed_id', class_name: 'ClosedPosition'
  has_many :closer_stock_positions, foreign_key: 'closer_id', class_name: 'ClosedPosition'
end`

Comment: Right before you added this, I actually figured it out. All I had to do was rename the foreign_key in my `ClosedPosition` column to be `port_stock_id` and then adjust the association accordingly. Adding an answer now. Thanks for the effort though! Your solution looks like it could work, but I haven't tested it because I already did my migration.